# how to connect two java applets (through a JButton & a common database(jdbc))?

Tags: java, database, swing, applet, jbutton

In my project file, I've created two different applets. They both work upon same database but my problem after deployment there'll be two different files for separate applet. The working is supposed to be like: get some input data from first applet. store it in database. **Hit the continue button & the second applet gets invoked** . The second applet should read from database written by first applet and process.

[**first applet**](http://pastebin.com/RBYiP7na)

[**second applet**](http://pastebin.com/U2eKBajP) (P.S. its not complete yet, connectivity issues(this question))

Comment: Don't use applets, they are deprecated technology which will stop working soon as browsers are starting to remove support.

Comment: college complusions :|

Comment: 1) Please refer the teacher to [Why CS teachers should **stop** teaching Java applets](http://programmers.blogoverflow.com/2013/05/why-cs-teachers-should-stop-teaching-java-applets/). 2) See [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free). ..

Comment: .. 3) Better than the current approach would be to have a single applet using a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).